# Upload "public" directory to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Using this command from SSH I can upload a whole folder into Google Cloud Storage:

```
gsutil cp -R folder_big gs://bucket_name
```

Those are files inside the folder:

[image]

I don't want to click individually on each file to make it public.

How do I make the folder (and all files inside) automatically public on upload?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do:

```
gsutil cp -a public-read -R folder_big gs://bucket_name
```

Note: if it's a large folder you would likely get a substantial performance improvement if you use the multi-threading option:

```
gsutil -m cp -a public-read -R folder_big gs://bucket_name
```